# Extends Grid View and OnitemclickListenner

Tags: android, gridview, onclicklistener

I am trying to make a custom Gridview from the native Gridview and override the onitemclick. But it never catches the clicks on my custom gridview

Here is my code:

------------Custom GridView class------------

```
public class MyGridView extends android.widget.GridView implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;
public MyGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightSpec = heightMeasureSpec;
    if (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >>2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
}



@Override
public void setOnItemClickListener( OnItemClickListener l )
{
    System.out.println("MPIKA");
    mListener = l;
    super.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}




@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    System.out.println("test");
}


  }
```

------------Main Class------------

```
  public class Store extends Activity implements MyGridView.OnItemClickListener {
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stores);
    initialize();

}
 private void initialize() {
    
    openShops = new ArrayList<StoreClass>();
    closedShops = new ArrayList<StoreClass>();
    open = (MyGridView) findViewById(R.id.open);
    open.setOnItemClickListener(this);
     ......  
}

   /*
     @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
        builder1.setMessage("Παρακαλώ επιλέξτε τύπο πακέτου");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.show();
    TextView messageText = (TextView)alert11.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    alert11.show();
}*/
}
```

---

UPDATE

---xml------------

```
 <ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
  <cyprusFood.on.adapters.MyGridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/OpenStores"
    android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/open"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp">

    </cyprusFood.on.adapters.MyGridView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"``
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="7 καταστήματα εκτός ωραρίου λειτουργίας"
    android:id="@+id/CloseStores"
    android:layout_below="@+id/open"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/OpenStores"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/OpenStores"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

<cyprusFood.on.adapters.MyGridView
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CloseStores"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="6dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"></cyprusFood.on.adapters.MyGridView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Update 2

https://web.archive.org/web/20210117125708/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/09/extending-and-customizing-gridview-with.html

I tried this but not working

Comment: Are you seeing any of the log messages?

Comment: Try using `Log.d("someTag","someMessage");` instead of `System.out.println("someMessage");`

Comment: Syso is ok :P the problem is onclickListener because i use custom Gridview.

Comment: You never know! :P Well the code looks right to me. Weird that not even "MPIKA" is printed. If there was another problem with you custom class or xml you would probably get a NullPointerException or ClassCastException.

Comment: I replace my Syso's with Log.d ... but nothing

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried putting some breakpoints in the code? That would really rule out a simple DDMS error of some sort.

Comment: Nothing on click ..... with debug ... Tomorrow i will this lib:  https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders